# Finite additivity plus a restricted form of sigma-additivity suffice for a set function to be a probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

> Suppose $\beta$ is a sigma field of subsets of $\Omega$. 
>    and suppose $p: \beta \to [0; 1]$ is a set function satisfying:
>
> 1. $p$ is finitely additive on $ \beta $.
> 2. $p(\Omega) = 1$.
> 3. If $(A_n)$ are disjoint sets and $\bigcup_n A_n =\Omega $ then $\sum_n p(A_n)=1 $ then show that $p$ is a probability measure.

We just need to show that $p$ is $\sigma $ additive.

For that I was wondering how could I use the given condition 3.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(B_{n})$ be any disjoint sequence in $\beta$. Let $B =(\cup_{n}B_{n})^{c}$. Then the $B_{n}$ are disjoint from $B$ and $(\cup_{n} B_{n}) \cup B = \Omega$.

By (3), $\sum_{n}p(B_{n}) = 1 -p(B) = p(B^{c}) = p(\cup_{n}B_{n})$.